# Source code of the patches for Shellshock

Tags: bash, source, patch, shellshock

I have a project for my grad level OS class, and I have decided to choose the Shellshock vulnerability bugs as my topic.  There is a lot of great information out there, but I was curious if it is possible to get the source code of patches that resolved the bugs related to Shellshock.  Namely,

```
CVE-2014-6271, CVE-2014-6277, CVE-2014-6278, CVE-2014-7169, CVE-2014-7186, CVE-2014-7187
```

I was able to find some source code [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.bash.bugs/22190), but I was wondering if anyone could point me to a comprehensive list of patch source.  Or, which would be great, if someone could explain how I can access the patch source on my machine (since I have upgraded my machine and am no longer vulnerable).

Comment: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/

Comment: Wow thank you! Can't believe I couldn't find that!

Comment: When you install software, upgrades, patches from repositories you are downloading pre-compiled packages. If you are not being specific about downloading source your system won't do it.